# Reference of the relative word "where"

Tags: word-usage, relative-clauses

> At first glance, calcite might be confused with quartz **where** both are clear, colorless, and "glassy".

I'm not familiar with the use of "where" here, which usually refers to a place.
In this usage, does it refer to the situation at which calcite is confused with quartz?  Is there any other(better?) ways to express the idea？

Comment: That sentence confuses me. I think it's supposed to mean, "*... with quartz **because both can be** clear...*", in which case, "where" is incorrect. If it's correct, then it means something like, "*... with quartz, **in situations where** both are clear...*", but would mean they were found side-by-side, in nature, which I don't believe is the intent here

Comment: @gotube  I googled it  and got several hits but  none of them is from a reliable source.  Now I can conclude that this is a bad sentence.

Comment: "Where" has been bleached of its locative meaning and here probably means something like "because" or "since".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many textbooks insist that "where" be used only to indicate a place, but in practice English speakers use it in a variety of contexts. I searched Google News and quickly found this example:

> [Clever KBRD is a breakout where you bounce balls with your keyboard skills](https://www.pcgamer.com/clever-kbrd-is-a-breakout-where-you-bounce-balls-with-your-keyboard-skills/)

In this headline, "breakout" represents a type of computer game, not a place.

In your sentence, it is hard to tell whether the author means that "both are clear, colorless, and 'glassy'" in a specific situation or in general. If the latter is true, then "whereas" would probably have been a better word to use (and might have been what the author intended). [M-W defines "whereas"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whereas) thus:

> in view of the fact that : SINCE